# is there any way to move cursor multiple lines at the time in sublime text with keyboard shortcut instead of one line at the time?

Tags: cursor, move, text-editor, lines

I used to move cursor up and down with "UP" and "DOWN" keys.
but it can only move 1 line at the time.
sometimes I would love to move 2 or 3 lines at the time. 
i'm wondering if thers's such feature in sublime text editor ?

Answer (score 2):

You can record a macro (CTRL+Q or Tools -> Record/Stop Macro) and save it (just use cursor up/down as often as you like.

Then assign a key or key-combination to the macro file. The key assignement has to look like this. I called the macros "multiple_lines_down" and "multiple_lines_up".
Then assign the macros to your keymap:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+down"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/multiple_lines_down.sublime-macro"}},
{ "keys": ["alt+up"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/multiple_lines_up.sublime-macro"}},
```

Macro-File (5 times up) looks like this. Replace `false` with `true` to move downwards or just record another macro.

```
[
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": false
        },
        "command": "move"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": false
        },
        "command": "move"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": false
        },
        "command": "move"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": false
        },
        "command": "move"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": false
        },
        "command": "move"
    }
]
```